# difference between two strings

Tags: php, compare

```
$first = 1,2,3,4,5;
$second = 1,3,5,6;
```

I need to get difference of those two, so that result would be like:
`$result = 2,4,6;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you mean

```
$first = "1,2,3,4,5";
$second = "1,3,5,6";
```

then try

```
$first_array = explode(",", $first);
$second_array = explode(",", $second);
$result_array = array_merge(array_diff($first_array, $second_array), array_diff($second_array, $first_array));
$result = implode("," $result_array);
```

Answer (score 3):

try this:

```
implode(',',array_diff(explode(',',$first),explode(',',$second)));
```

**EDIT:**

updated to fully diff (found on PHP.net and modified):

```
$first = explode(',', $first);
$second = explode(',', $second);
echo implode(',',array_diff(array_merge($first, $second), array_intersect($first, $second)));
```

Comment: `array_diff` wouldn't return the `6` I don't think

Comment: `array_diff` _Compares array1 against array2 and returns the difference_ - have to merge both ways.  check my answer

Comment: @AaronW. Thank you for clarifying.  I wasn't aware of this.  I've modified my answer after seeing another way in the comments for [array_diff()](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php) on PHP.net

Answer (score 0):

first, i'll assume that your strings are properly quoted as strings:

```
$first = "1,2,3,4,5";
$second = "1,3,5,6";
$diff_string = array_diff(explode(",", $first), explode(",", $second));
$diff_array = implode(",", $diff_string);
```