# Comparing Path String With Wildcard in PHP

Tags: php, string, compare

Howto to compare this string :

```
commodity/search/oil/branch/index
```

with this :

```
commodity/search/*/branch/index
```

It should return true although "oil" is replace with other word.

Comment: how about some regular expression?

Comment: Try this substituting / for the comma   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9692914/difference-between-two-strings

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$match = preg_match("/commodity\/search\/(.*)\/branch\/index/", "commodity/search/someotherword/branch/index");
```

`$match` will be true (or some value evaluating to true, like 1) if a match is found.

Note: the above will match on any extra path, such as `commodity/search/some/other/word/branch/index`

If you just want to match a single word, but not something resembling a path structure, then you might try something like this:

```
$match = preg_match("/commodity\/search\/[A-Za-z0-9_-]+\/branch\/index/", "commodity/search/some-OTHER_word/branch/index");
```

This will only match against upper and lower case a-z characters, numbers, hyphens and underscores. Adjust as needed.

Comment: Or it can be `'/commodity\/search\/[^\/:\\;]+\/branch\/index/"`.

Comment: Howto to construct the pattern dynamically?

Answer (score 1):

PHP has a built-in function for this called [fnmatch()](http://php.net/fnmatch).

It provides usage of basic wildcards.

```
<?php

if (fnmatch('commodity/search/*/branch/index', 'commodity/search/oil/branch/index')) {
    echo "It matches!";
}
```

It is not supported on non-POSIX compliant systems though (see PHP manual).